# Under what conditions is the answer box replaced with an "Answer this question" button?

Tags: support, answers

Today, I stumbled upon a [question on Workplace Stack Exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12067/33983) to flag a spam post. I noticed that the 'new answer editor' which usually appears at the bottom of the page was replaced by an 'Answer this question' button:

[image]

Upon clicking it, a popup appears starting with

> This question has more than 2 answers already.

So that's the *reason* it appears, but I was wondering what the full set of conditions is. [This post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4050/33983) indicates Workplace has a custom threshold set to 'more than 2 answers'; it mentions [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) which upon testing seems to have a 'more than 5 answers' threshold. For most sites, it seems to be 'more than 30 answers'. Are there more exceptions? What about Meta sites?

Also, is there any reputation level/privilege above which you don't get this popup anymore?

Comment: I know it's the FR that caused the implementation but it pretty much answers your question entirely, so I'm not sure it's worth tracking the information in two places.